# Resize image with css and copy it to JS with aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, html, css, image-processing

I want to resize  image with CSS and then copy it to JS variable with same width, height and aspect ratio as in img tag. Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: what do you mean by "copy it to js"?

Comment: I meant variable. For example I need to copy it to new Image(), but keeping same aspect ratio as in img renders it

Comment: I tried nothing so far, so any suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but you can assign elements a class and modify it in CSS.

Comment: I'm trying to copy the result of css rule to javascript. When I take src attribute from result img tag it gives me original size and height, but I need it to be same size and aspect ratio as in img tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to add the CSS to the JS to begin with. In the example below, the CSS is not defined until it is added by the function.

HTML:

```
<img id="myImage" 
src="http://res.publicdomainfiles.com/pdf_view/185/14006695215558.jpg" 
alt="image">
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function imageSize() {
    let img_1 = document.getElementById('myImage');
    img_1 = img.style.width = "100px";
}

imageSize()
```